# Error 0xC0000005: Access Violation when returning from a function C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in this language and I have encountered this problem. After searching on net it seems it is related to memory allocation,pointers etc.. which I didn't quite understood.... Here I am trying to add data through class to a binary file...
So I would like to ask what the problem can be-->

```
void addques()
{
    question abc;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("question.txt",ios::app|ios::binary);
    cout<<"Enter Question!\n";
    gets(abc.ques);
    cout<<"Enter Options!\n";
    gets(abc.option1);gets(abc.option2);gets(abc.option3);gets(abc.option4);
    cout<<"Enter correct option number\n";
    cin>>abc.k;
    cout<<"Enter question nummber"; cin>>abc.quesno;
    fout.write((char*)&abc,sizeof(abc));
    fout.close();
    cout<<"File closed";
}
```

It seems all the functions that have ifstream/ofstream class objects are showing this error. The last line "File Closed" is also being executed and after that errors shows up.
Could it be this line-- `fout.write((char*)&abc,sizeof(abc))`; ???
Kindly Help

This is the related class-->

```
class question
{   public:
    char ques[80];
    char option1[50], option2[50], option3[50], option4[50];
    char k;
    char quesno;
};
```

For the whole program I pasted my code here 
http://pastebin.com/S7KNby0E
Kindly see it...because I was unable to do so here

Comment: Post the destructor for your question class.

Comment: Please post the source for `question`

Comment: Well I'm guess that the answer is related to the bit 'you didn't quite understand'. But no-one will know until you post the code for your `question` class.

Comment: class question
{   public:
    char ques[80];
    char option1[50],option2[50],option3[50],option4[50];
    char k;
    char quesno;
};

Comment: What fields does `question` consist of?

Comment: Have you thought about reducing the code to the bare minimum  exhibiting the problem? And please learn to format your question somewhat in a readable...

Comment: Assuming you haven't tried to enter more characters than your arrays will hold then there is no reason for that code to crash. The error must be in the code you didn't post. Why not post the whole program?

Comment: My program is not completed, just some functions and their function call in void main()...Would it help if I post whole program?

Comment: @Harsh: YES!!!! As long as it's not too lengthy. One of the issues in C++ programming is an error in one part of the code can cause a crash in another part of the code. Beginners seem to have a knack of posting all the stuff that doesn't matter and failing to post the real problem.

Comment: @Harsh: Depends, the less code you post the easier it is to wade through, but if you post to little your code won't contain the error. So the best option would be to remove as much code as possible while still getting the error from the program (by commenting it out) and post only whats left.

Comment: I am not able to properly format the source code..so the site is not letting me post..still new..

Comment: You should choose whether you want to write C or C++.  What you have here is a conglomeration of both. They're not the same language, though it may seem so at first.  Pick a paradigm and go with it.

Comment: Is there any harm is using both? We are being taught very basic C++ and some concepts of C are also used..

Comment: If this is homework, then please tag it as such.

Comment: @Harsh: More confusing. Good style in C is different from good style in C++. Try both and you'll just get a mess, especially when you are just beginning.

Comment: @RichardSitze I have to prepare a project and I will be marked on this. But then I am not asking you to write the program, I am just asking to help me sort out the problem like any general user. I don't find the need to tag it as homework. Should I?

Comment: @Harsh: The way to solve this is to do what Grizzly says. Cut down your code as much as you can, until you have the smallest possible code that is still giving you this problem. Then post all the code. Ignore all the people saying to use this method or that method, it's good advice in general but it's not what you need right now. Create a new question if you think it will help.

Comment: The code that gives me problem is the functions which contains this "type" of line --->  'fo.write((char*)password,sizeof(password));'

Comment: And when I call these sort of functions in my main(), it wont't return back to main but rather always encounter this error. But the problem goes  as soon as I put my code of the function (eg- addques()) into main directly without any function call, then it works...Any help?

Comment: Well it seems likely that `password` is a null pointer. But as usual need to see more code. Eventually people are going to get tired of guessing, please post complete code.

Comment: @jahhaj I wrote 'fo.write((char*)password,sizeof(password));' this just for and example.I meant to say the function that contain this sort of line are the cause of the problem but I don't know why..

Comment: @jahhaj just tell me how to format the code so the site would allow me to post

Comment: @Harsh: you will notice probably that sizeof can behave confusingly in some cases, so I'll explain that too in my answer.

Comment: @jahhaj {} is not working since my program already contains many {} I think it thinks of them as the ending } and which results is awkwardly formatted code

Comment: @jahhaj   The program is here http://pastebin.com/S7KNby0E

Comment: @Harsh: What can I say. I took your program and it ran without crashing. I looked very hard at the code and I couldn't see anything wrong that would cause the crash and error message you see. I have no idea why this code would crash. Sorry I can't be more help. (The only thing I can think of is that you are entering more characters than your character arrays can handle, but I assume you already know about that danger.)

Comment: This is almost entirely old C code, and little C++.

Comment: @RichardSitze - homework meta-tags aren't helpful. If it's homework and if the question meets the minimum quality standards for the site then it's good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Are you entering a question or answer that's too long for one of your buffers?  I'd bet you are, and it's overrunning the bounds of the class and corrupting the stack.   Also, mixing cin and cout and the C style IO functions like gets is asking for trouble, so don't.

Since you're using C++, you don't have to do string manipulation as character arrays.  There is a STL class that handles all of the memory crap for you.  I'd rewrite your class in the following way:

```
class Question
{   public:
    string ques;
    string option1, option2, option3, option4;
    char k;
    char quesno;

    void write(fstream& f)
    {
        f << ques.length() << " " << ques << endl
          << option1.length() << " " << option1 << endl
          << option2.length() << " " << option2 << endl
          << option3.length() << " " << option3 << endl
          << option4.length() << " " << option4 << endl
          << k << " " << quesno << endl;
    }
};
```

and your function in the following way:

```
void addques()
{
    Question abc;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("question.txt", ios::app);

    cout << "Enter Question!" << endl;
    getline (cin, abc.ques);

    cout << "Enter Options!\n";
    getline(cin, abc.option1);
    getline(cin, abc.option2);
    getline(cin, abc.option3);
    getline(cin, abc.option4);

    cout << "Enter correct option number: ";
    cin >> abc.k;

    cout << "Enter question number: ";
    cin >> abc.quesno;

    // you will have to change your writing method a bit because you can't just write the string object straight to disk like you were before

    abc.write(fout);
    fout.close();
}
```

You should then be able to read one into a stream with the extraction operator in more or less the same way write works.

### Ascii to Binary

Since you have to use binary, you can store the integer values as binary values in the following way:

```
int i = ques.length();
fout.write((const char *) &i, sizeof(i));
```

This will write the 32 bit integer value directly to the stream without converting it to a string first.  Your strings will then have the following format:

```
+     0x0     0x1     0x2     0x3     0x4     0x5     0x6     0x7     
0x0  [0x00    0x00    0x00    0xC0  ][H       E       L       L
0x8   O       <space> W       O       R       L       D       <null> ]
```

The length is the first 4 bytes, shown here as 0x0000000C (integer value 12).  The string follows immediately, and has the value "HELLO WORLD\0".  \0 is the null terminator.  In my example, this length includes the null terminator.

### sizeof

Sizeof is an operator that produces the size in memory of the specified type as best as the compiler can determine.  For integral types, such as int, short, char, etc, it will return the number of bytes used by the type.  For arrays, you might run into confusing behavior.  If called on an array declared statically to be of a fixed size, sizeof will return the array's length * the size of one element.

```
int derp[1000];
sizeof(derp); // sizeof(int) * 1000
```

If the compiler does not know how big the array is, what you will get is the size of a pointer to the first element.  So be careful.  You can't use sizeof on a pointer to determine array size.

```
int derp2[];
sizeof(derp2); // sizeof(int *), probably 4 or 8
int * derp3 = derp;
sizeof(derp3); // sizeof(int *), probably 4 or 8
```

To get the length of a std::string (the STL string class), use the length member:

```
string hurr = "hello world";
hurr.length(); // does NOT include the null terminator
               // length of string AND terminator is hurr.length() + 1
```

Comment: It's all very good except (God knows why) he's trying to do binary I/O.

Comment: He used to just be writing the exact memory contents of the struct to disk, but its probably easier to let formatted insertion and extraction take care of that.  Besides, ascii is just a subset of binary.

Comment: Actually, It's a project that I have to submit in school and we have to use data file handling using binary files so I have to use it,but then again I am running in all sorts of problem which are beyond my capability to understand

Comment: Take my code and modify it then to store the lengths as binary integers instead of formatted strings.  I'll add an example in my answer.

Comment: @RichardSitze: he didn't admit it was homework until he commented on my answer.  That said, I gave him an ascii implementation.  Converting it to binary is an exercise for him.  I gave him an idea to work with, and I'll let him connect the dots to a working solution.

Comment: @Wug Thankyou..I will follow your advice realted to sizeof

Answer (score 1):

There's a clear problem, and many potential problems.  Your symptom suggests a value got written into memory somewhere it shouldn't have (buffer overrun, floating pointer, etc).

### Concerns

1. Don't mix C++ standard stream I/O (std::cout, std:cerr, std:cin, std::ofstream, and many many more elements) with C-style standard I/O ([gets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets)).  Choose [one I/O library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), and stick with it.
2. Check and verify your assumptions regarding boundary conditions.  Your boundaries in this case are the size of your input char arrays in `question`.  Is your input data approaching/nearing the array sizes (the limits you defined)?  Did you allow room for an extra terminating NULL (0) character at the end of each char array?
3. Pre-initialize EVERYTHING you're going to be working with.  What can your `question` constructor do to ensure neutral "empty data" exists in a new `question`?

### Strategy - Isolate the problem

1. Comment out the entire function body (all statements), leaving the function empty.  Run and verify that it works or not - this will identify if the problem is in the body, or somewhere else.
2. start adding bits back in.  Identify exactly what statement triggers the problem.  There is concern, with access violations, that this type of code-triage may not reveal the true culprit.

EXCEPT: buffer overruns, floating pointers, and such can cause problems anywhere at anytime after the problem occurs.  All the problem isolation in the world may not identify the source of the problem.  You'll be developing skills to recognize common problems.   The points above are intended to be some starting guidelines to help you develop those skills.

### Style

1. Declare each variable as near as possible to it's point of first use in the code.  Consider moving the declaration for `fout` down.

Comment: So I should use cin.getline instead of gets?

Comment: That's one, reasonable, options.  Good place to start.

Comment: And what do you mean by "That you're using 'gets' suggests strongly that it's using character arrays at best, or pointers referencing "nothing" at worst." I don't get this part

Comment: gets only works with character arrays and pointers. In C++ it's generally considered better to use strings.

Comment: So in short gets is better if am dealing with character array?

Comment: @Harsh NO.  that's not what he said :-)

Comment: @jahhaj In his case, his `question class` is avoiding direct and indirect pointers/references.

Comment: @Harsh It's not a question of which is better, each has strengths/weaknesses.  You're learning C++, stick with the C++ library and learn it well before confusing yourself with both (with conflicting mechanisms).